# OutOfMemoryError: Trying to optimise Maven multi-module unit tests using HSQLDB, DBUnit, unitils, Hibernate, Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring, hsqldb, out-of-memory, dbunit

I have a big multi-module Maven project with thousands of tests.
Each test loads DAOs, services, etc using the SpringApplicationContext annotation.
My unitils configuration looks like this:

```
database.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
database.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:mytestdb
database.schemaNames=PUBLIC
database.userName=sa
database.password=
database.dialect=hsqldb
unitils.modules=database,dbunit,hibernate,inject,spring
# custom version of HsqldbDbSupport which calls "SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE"
org.unitils.core.dbsupport.DbSupport.implClassName.hsqldb=my.company.unitils.HsqldbDbSupport
org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.IDataTypeFactory.implClassName.hsqldb=org.dbunit.ext.hsqldb.HsqldbDataTypeFactory
org.unitils.dbmaintainer.structure.ConstraintsDisabler.implClassName=org.unitils.dbmaintainer.structure.impl.DefaultConstraintsDisabler
# custom version of CleanInsertLoadStrategy which calls "DatabaseUnitils.disableConstraints();"
DbUnitModule.DataSet.loadStrategy.default=my.company.unitils.DataSetLoadStrategy
HibernateModule.configuration.implClassName=org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration
dbMaintainer.disableConstraints.enabled=true
dbMaintainer.cleanDb.enabled=true
dbMaintainer.generateDataSetStructure.enabled=false
dataSetStructureGenerator.xsd.dirName=target/xsd
dbMaintainer.autoCreateExecutedScriptsTable=true
updateDataBaseSchema.enabled=false
dbMaintainer.fromScratchEnabled=true
```

My Hibernate configuration looks like this:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=false
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.connection.autocommit=false
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=false
hibernate.generate_statistics=false
```

When I run the tests, the 2GB allocated for heap eventually fills up. Permgen reaches about 400MB.
Looking at the heap dump, **char**, **java.lang.String** and **java.lang.String[]** takes up about 40% of the total instances.

When I spot-check a few of these instances, the GC root traces back to:

- the Spring context manager (in the form of context XML extracts)
- the SessionFactory (in the form of queries)

I would like to optimise these 2 things, and I *think* they are respectively caused by:

- Each test has a @SpringApplicationContext annotation
- Each test also uses the unitils @DataSet annotation to load up data for that test.

Note, I use jdbc:hsqldb:file to offload some data off of the heap (i.e. instead of using jdbc:hsqldb:mem)

Versions:
hsqldb 1.8.0.7
Spring 3.0.4.RELEASE
unitils 3.1

**PS** can someone with a 1500+ rating please tag this question with "unitils"?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but the queries in the session factory are IMO the named queries and the queries for the CRUD on your entities, they are not related to the @DataSet annotations (DbUnit uses JDBC).

Comment: I can't add the tag unitils: there is a maximum of 5 tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the memory is taken by the data stored in the database, you can make the database use disk based tables to reduce memory use. This can be specified on the database URL:

database.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:mytestdb;hsqldb.default_table_type=cached

Comment: OK, I've settled on a test MySQL instance for integration tests. The unit tests use an in-memory DB, but tear down anything they've saved when the test completes.